# Backpropagation Using Tensorflow and Numpy MSE not Dropping

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, backpropagation

I am trying to create a Backpropagation but I do not want to use the GradientDescentOptimizer from TF. I just wanted to update my own weights and biases. The problem is that the Mean Square Error or Cost is not approaching to zero. It just stays at some 0.2xxx. Is it because of my inputs which are 520x1600 (yes, each input has 1600 units and yes, there are 520 of them) or my number of neurons in the Hidden Layer is problematic? I have tried implementing this using the GradientDescentOptimizer and minimize(cost) which is working fine (Cost reduces near to zero as training goes on) but maybe I have an issue in my code of updating the weights and biases.

Here's my code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from BPInputs40 import pattern, desired;

#get the inputs and desired outputs, 520 inputs, each has 1600 units
train_in = pattern
train_out = desired

learning_rate=tf.constant(0.5)
num_input_neurons = len(train_in[0])
num_output_neurons = len(train_out[0])
num_hidden_neurons = 20

#weight matrix initialization with random values
w_h = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([num_input_neurons, num_hidden_neurons]), dtype=tf.float32)
w_o = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([num_hidden_neurons, num_output_neurons]), dtype=tf.float32)
b_h = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1, num_hidden_neurons]), dtype=tf.float32)
b_o = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1, num_output_neurons]), dtype=tf.float32)

# Model input and output
x = tf.placeholder("float")
y = tf.placeholder("float")

def sigmoid(v):
  return tf.div(tf.constant(1.0),tf.add(tf.constant(1.0),tf.exp(tf.negative(v*0.001))))
def derivative(v):
  return tf.multiply(sigmoid(v), tf.subtract(tf.constant(1.0), sigmoid(v)))

output_h = tf.sigmoid(tf.add(tf.matmul(x,w_h),b_h))
output_o = tf.sigmoid(tf.add(tf.matmul(output_h,w_o),b_o)) 

error = tf.subtract(output_o,y)  #(1x35)
mse = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(error))

delta_o=tf.multiply(error,derivative(output_o)) 
delta_b_o=delta_o
delta_w_o=tf.matmul(tf.transpose(output_h), delta_o)
delta_backprop=tf.matmul(delta_o,tf.transpose(w_o))
delta_h=tf.multiply(delta_backprop,derivative(output_h))
delta_b_h=delta_h
delta_w_h=tf.matmul(tf.transpose(x),delta_h)

#updating the weights
train = [
  tf.assign(w_h, tf.subtract(w_h, tf.multiply(learning_rate, delta_w_h))),
  tf.assign(b_h, tf.subtract(b_h, tf.multiply(learning_rate, tf.reduce_mean(delta_b_h, 0)))), 
  tf.assign(w_o, tf.subtract(w_o, tf.multiply(learning_rate, delta_w_o))), 
  tf.assign(b_o, tf.subtract(b_o, tf.multiply(learning_rate, tf.reduce_mean(delta_b_o, 0))))
]

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

err,target=1, 0.005
epoch, max_epochs = 0, 2000000
while epoch < max_epochs:
  epoch += 1
  err, _ = sess.run([mse, train],{x:train_in,y:train_out})
  if (epoch%1000 == 0):
    print('Epoch:', epoch, '\nMSE:', err)

answer = tf.equal(tf.floor(output_o + 0.5), y)
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(answer, "float"))
print(sess.run([output_o], feed_dict={x: train_in, y: train_out}));
print("Accuracy: ", (1-err) * 100 , "%");
```

**Update:** I got it working now. The MSE dropped to almost zero once I increased the number of neurons in the hidden layer. I tried using 5200 and 6400 neurons for the hidden layer and with just 5000 epochs, the accuracy was almost 99%. Also, the largest learning rate I used is 0.1 because when above that, the MSE will not be close to zero.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert in this field, but it looks like your weights are updated correctly. And the fact that your MSE decreases from some higher values to 0.2xxx is the strong indicator of that. I would definitely try to run this problem with way more hidden neurons (e.g. 500)

Btw, are your inputs normalized? If not, that obviously could be the reason

Comment: My inputs are just 0's and 1's. Like a black pixel is 1 and 0 for the white pixel. My image size per sample is 40x40 that's why I have 1600 input neurons.